# Safari facing MSAL login issue with Angular 8, login works fine in chrome, edge

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I am getting an error in console window - Safari Browser, using MSAL for authentication in angular8 application.
Login functionality works fine without any error in other browsers like chrome, IE, Edge etc.
Can someone please help here.

Error : Uncaught (in promise): ClientAuthError : AcquireToken_In_Progress: Error during login call- login is already in progress.

Comment: I have the same issue. End of last summer a browser security update came out and broke our (React based) MSAL code. We were able to get all browsers working except Safari on iMac. We authenticate fine it just throws when we try to get a token silently. Directed our users to use Chrome with our app on iMac.

Comment: Update: Safari 14.0.2 is working with our MSAL code. Safari 13.1.2 on High Sierra(10.13.6) does not.